How do I solve this error in a flutter app "Could not find com.google.android.material:material:1.13.0"?
I added Appcompat to my project and my app has been failing to build with different errors that I have been trying to solve. And in doing so I added the following dependencies to my android.app/build.gradle:
dependencies {
   implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
   implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.13.0'
}

but now I am having the error below:
[+1987 ms] > Task :app:checkDebugAarMetadata
[        ] Resource missing. [HTTP GET: https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/android/material/material/1.13.0/material-1.13.0.pom]
[ +299 ms] Resource missing. [HTTP GET: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/google/android/material/material/1.13.0/material-1.13.0.pom]
[ +899 ms] Resource missing. [HTTP GET:`your text` https://storage.googleapis.com/download.flutter.io/com/google/android/material/material/1.13.0/material-1.13.0.pom]
[ +201 ms] > Task :app:checkDebugAarMetadata FAILED
[   +5 ms] FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
[   +6 ms] * What went wrong:``your text``
[        ] Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'.
[        ] > Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
[        ]    > Could not find com.google.android.material:material:1.13.0.
[        ]      Searched in the following locations:
[        ]        - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/android/material/material/1.13.0/material-1.13.0.pom
[        ]        - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/google/android/material/material/1.13.0/material-1.13.0.pom
[        ]        - https://storage.googleapis.com/download.flutter.io/com/google/android/material/material/1.13.0/material-1.13.0.pom
[   +3 ms]      Required by:
[        ]          project :app`


I have tried to run mvn install as outlined below to no avail:
https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/packages/81484
